# Error during running mysqldump for creating tar archive

Tags: linux, backup, compression, tar, archiving

I created mysqldump for creating tar archive but every time I received notice

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
```

Using `gzip` created archive normally but with `tar` I can't move forward.

```
mysqldump --all-databases --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false > /var/thg/vmest/full-backup-$(date +%F).sql \
| tar -czvf /var/thg/vmest/full-backup-$(date +%F).sql.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here.

First, you're redirecting (`>`) `mysqldump` output to a file, so nothing gets to `tar` through the pipe (`|`).

But even if you passed the data to `tar`, it wouldn't work. Common uses of `tar` are:

1. Read files and make an archive (`tar -cf archive.tar foo bar`).
2. Read files and write to stdout (`tar -cf - foo bar`).
3. Read an archive and extract, i.e. create files (`tar -xf archive.tar`).
4. Read stdin and extract, i.e. create files (`tar -xf -`).

There is no mode to read from stdin and create an archive. The whole point of `tar` is to pack *files* into a *single* file or stream, so the separate files can be recreated later. Technically you can pack one file into a tar archive and sometimes this is justified:

- when you want to store the file with its permissions, ownership etc. on a filesystem that doesn't support these features; `tar` will store the metadata;
- when it's a part of a *routine*, where you *always* use `tar` to store files, but at this particular day there is just one file to store; there is no point to make an exception for this edge case.

Packing a stream into a tar archive or stream gives no advantage, it makes no sense. Just save the original stream to a file or pass it further. There's really no job for `tar` in this case.

I can see you want to compress the stream. Passing it to `gzip` is what you need:

```
mysqldump --all-databases --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false | gzip -c > /var/thg/vmest/full-backup-$(date +%F).sql.gz
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil, I have already created archive using gzip and was able to restore one of DB to mysql . My manager asked me to use tar.

Comment: Thanks for your help and clarification.